# boost::scoped_array::get() in return statement

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I have the following code:

```
std::string HtmlToText( std::string const& html )
{
    boost::scoped_array<char> text( converter.toText( html.c_str() ) );
    return text.get();
}
```

My concern with this code was whether or not object `text` would be destructed after `text.get()` returns but before the temporary return object `std::string` gets constructed. This would be a problem if it would be destructed at that time.

I searched around the C++03 standard for the rules and specifics on when to destruct objects in relation to the return statement in function scope, but I had no luck finding what I wanted. Can anyone help me find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the text of the C++03 draft at hand but I seem to recall that any temporary created from the call will be destructed before the actual `text` object is deleted (LIFO ordering of automatic objects in block scope) and this should guarantee that you never run into this issue.